# Typescript narrowing and control flow problem

Tags: typescript

Using typescript 4.4.4

I have done my research on Typescript narrowing and the error below should be mananaged automatically.

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'string'.   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```js
if(typeof f.value === 'string'){
                result = doesStringContainsKeyword(row[name], f.value)
                console.log({result})
            }
```

setting `row[name] as string` fixes the errors, but TS should have handled it automatically

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-vaughan-dyqi1?file=/src/index.ts

```js
const data:IRow[] = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "customer": "Dander Mente",
        "address": "NY USA",
        "order": "A4BC",
        "tax": 145.20,
        "total": 13.9
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "customer": "Tracey Bill",
        "address": "NJ USA",
        "order": "A8O7X",
        "tax": 1.20,
        "total": 93.46
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "customer": "Danny Prince",
        "address": "Pili  NY USA",
        "order": "AB0C",
        "tax": 14.60,
        "total": 33.9
    }
]


interface IFiltersString {
    name: keyof IRow,
    value: string,
}

interface IFiltersNumber {
    name: keyof IRow,
    value: number,
    op: Operators
}

type Operators = '>' | '<' | '>=' | '<=' | '==='


interface IRow {
    id: number,
    customer: string,
    address: string,
    order: string,
    tax: number,
    total: number,
}



function filterBy(  data: IRow[], filters:(IFiltersNumber | IFiltersString)[]){

    return  data.filter((row) => {

        let result = false

        let doesStringContainsKeyword = (string: string, keyword: string) => {
            return string.includes(keyword)
        }

        filters.forEach(f => {

            let name = f['name']
            if(typeof f.value === 'string'){
            //if filter value is string, it is assumed that row[name] is string, but i get error mentioned above. 
                result = doesStringContainsKeyword(row[name], f.value)
                console.log({result})
            }
        })


        return result

    })

}

console.log(filterBy(data, [{name: 'tax', value: 222, op: '<'}, {name: 'customer', value: 'Dan'}]));
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: You can pass in `[{ name: 'customer', value: 222, op: '<' }, { name: 'tax', value: 'Dan' }]` as your filters (swapping the `name` field arround) and the call is allowed by your typings, right?  So how can the compiler know that `row[name]` is a `string` when that's not even guaranteed in the call signature to `filterBy()`?  There are plenty of times when the compiler fails to handle things automatically, but this doesn't seem to be one of them.

Comment: So do you just want an answer saying that `row[name]` can indeed be `number`?  (which would answer "did I miss something")  Or are you looking for something else